# Get one hot vector in Keras embedding layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

Let's assume I have a number x.
This x can have some finite categorical values, by using the Embedding layer of Keras, this number x becomes a vector of embedding dimension.

Assume:

- E embedded vector.
- o one-hot encoded vector of x.
- W embedding matrix.

Then to make x to be a vector, we do E = Wo

Now, in order to retrieve E from Keras, we can execute the following code:

```
K.function([model.layers[0].input], [model.get_layer('embedding').output])([input_data])
```

While to retrieve W from Keras, we can execute:

```
model.get_layer('embedding').get_weights()
```

However, I have no idea how can I access vector o (since Keras automatically calculates it), which is one hot encoded version of x. Since I do not have any info about how the one-hot encoding is performed (precisely, the information regarding what value is mapped to which component), it does not seem to be that trivial to do it in another way.

Any answer to the question?

Comment: It is very simple, for an integer i, the i-th element of the vector is set to one, and the other elements are zero

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy But for instance, if I have possible integer category representation {-5, 8, 3}. What happens? Then I'm getting (1,0,0) for -5, (0,1,0) for 3, and (0,0,1) for 8, in a low to high order? Maybe it would be good for me to test it, if so, in order to convince myself :)

Comment: Nothing happens, that is an invalid input, the only allowed input is integers from 0 to size of vocabulary - 1

Comment: Awesome. Thanks a lot for your great answer, @Dr.Snoopy!